# Java: auto incrementation of id in constructor and adding items to arraylist

Tags: java, arraylist, data-structures, queue

I am writing a program to simulate a system in a college where students join a queue for ordering lunch at a cafetaria, each student is given a ticket number when he places his order, and then he takes a seat. When the order is ready, the ticket number corresponding to the order is displayed on a screen and the student can move to the counter to collect his lunch. The person at the counter can carry out three operation namely `recordOrder`, `requestCollection` and `displayPendingOrder`. The `recordOrder` operation allows order details to be input, an order is represented by a ticket ID, `tID`, and an arrayList of strings representing the items in the order. The `requestCollection` operation removes the first order from the queue, when it arrives from the kitchen (i.e. the order is ready). The `displayPendingOrder` operation displays all order which have not been delivered. Orders are delivered in the same order which they are received, i.e First In First Out.

Here is what I have done so far:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Queue;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Order_Main {
    private static class Order{
        private static int tID=0;
        private String itemName;

        public Order(String itemName){
            tID++;
            this.tID=tID;
            this.itemName=itemName;
        }

        public int gettID() {
            return tID;
        }

        public void settID(int tID) {
            this.tID = tID;
        }

        public String getItemName() {
            return itemName;
        }

        public void setItemName(String itemName) {
            this.itemName = itemName;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<Order> listOfItems= new ArrayList<Order>();
        recordOrder(listOfItems);
    }

    private static void recordOrder(ArrayList<Order> listOfItems){
        int n, num_Orders;
        String item = null;

        Scanner sc= new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Enter the number of orders.");
        num_Orders= sc.nextInt();

        for(int j=0; j<num_Orders;j++){
            System.out.println("Enter the number of items for token number "+(j+1));
            n=sc.nextInt();
            sc.nextLine();

            System.out.println("Enter the items: ");

            for(int i=0; i<n;i++){
                item=sc.nextLine();
            }

            listOfItems.add(new Order(item));
        }

        for(Order list: listOfItems){
            System.out.println("Token num: "+list.gettID()+ " Item name: "+list.getItemName());
        }
    }
}
```

I have currently only implemented the `recordOrder` function but here are some problems which I am facing:

1. In my `Order` class, I have auto-incremented the token number so that the first order will have a token number of 1, the second order of number 2 and so on.
   The problem is that the token number is getting incremented up to the number of orders and the number of orders is getting printed out as the token numbers. 
   That is suppose I enter the number of orders, `num_Orders`, as 3, I am getting an output of

Token num: 3 Item name: cheesecake

Token num: 3 Item name: fries

Token num: 3 Item name: burger

2. As I have shown in the output above, only the one and the last item which I have entered for a particular order is being printed out.
3. I can't figure out how to add the token and the arraylist of strings to a queue so that I can perform the other operations.

I am new to data structures and still learning so will be very grateful for any help, advice and suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to use the static variable tID as a member variable. You need another, non-static member variable that keeps track of the incremented id the order was assigned.

```
private static int tID=0;
private int orderId;
private String itemName;

public Order(String itemName){
    tID++;
    this.orderId = tID; //use this.orderId in the rest of Order's functions
    this.itemName = itemName;

}
```

Comment: It still didn't make any difference even though I added setters and getters for `orderId` also. The output is the same.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to you that do not use the token counter `(tID)` inside the class `order`, because the `order` class do not must know about how you calculate the token, is better if you handle the token counter inside the `main` function, something like this:

```
  import java.util.ArrayList;
  import java.util.LinkedList;
  import java.util.List;
  import java.util.Queue;
  import java.util.Scanner;

public class Order_Main {

private static class Order{

    private int orderID;
    private String itemName;

    public Order(int orderID,String itemName){
        this.orderID=orderID;
        this.itemName=itemName;

    }

    public int getOrderID() {
        return orderID;
    }

    public void setOrderID(int orderID) {
        this.orderID = orderID;
    }

    public String getItemName() {
        return itemName;
    }

    public void setItemName(String itemName) {
        this.itemName = itemName;
    }

}

public static void main(String[] args) {


    ArrayList<Order> listOfItems= new ArrayList<Order>();
    recordOrder(listOfItems);

}

    private static void recordOrder(ArrayList<Order> listOfItems){

        int n, num_Orders;
        String item = null;

        Scanner sc= new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Enter the number of orders.");
        num_Orders= sc.nextInt();

    for(int j=0; j<num_Orders;j++){
       System.out.println("Enter the number of items for token number "+(j+1));
       n=sc.nextInt();
       sc.nextLine();

    System.out.println("Enter the items: ");

    for(int i=0; i<n;i++){

        item=sc.nextLine();


    }

    listOfItems.add(new Order(j,item));

    }

 for(Order list: listOfItems){
     System.out.println("Token num: "+list.getOrderID()+ " Item name: "+list.getItemName());}   

      }

}
```